# How do you enable full horizontal scrolling on Mapkit?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I've added MapKit to an app I've been working on.  However, there appears to be a wall between Asia and America that you can't scroll past horizontally, to the right or to the left.

Is there an option to enable infinite horizontal scrolling, such that the map wraps around?

Comment: what you think the world is a sphere? According to google maps its flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in Mapkit as of now.